# C++ DLL and C# wrapper to interface with PCIe board

Tags: c#, c++, interrupt, pci-e

I have a C++ DLL which is communicating with a PCIe board. I also need to integrate it in a C# program, so I am writing a wrapper for it.
The DLL is written in C++ because I have a test app given by the producer of the board and also because I couldn’t find a way to interface with PCIe with .NET.
In a test app I receive interrupts from this board using WaitForSingleObject
This is the event defined

```
// Create an event handle to pass to the driver
        hEvent =
            CreateEvent(
                NULL,           // Not inheritable to child processes
                TRUE,           // Manual reset?
                FALSE,          // Intial state
                NULL            // Name of object
            );
```

And this is how it gets retrieved

```
// Wait for the event object
        EventStatus =
            WaitForSingleObject(
                (HANDLE)pEvent->hEvent,
                (DWORD)Timeout_ms
            );
```

How can I make a monitor to receive these interrupts continuously? (Infinite loop in DLL)?
And also, could you please tell me an efficient method to trigger an event in C# from this DLL?
Thanks for your help

Comment: `Infinite loop in DLL` - yes.

Comment: You know about C++/CLI, do you? That's an excellent use case for it.

Comment: @GSerg what do you mean? That doesn't sound right to me either. I was thinking about a thread

Comment: Can you add some more details @PMF or even just a link to look for further information

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/calling-native-functions-from-managed-code?view=msvc-170

Comment: I used DLLImport in my wrapper and defined functions that i successfully called.
I am having some trouble with calling a function that creates a thread in C++ that should trigger an event in C#. Probably I am not too clear :(

Comment: @Danilo7 It's going to be a loop anyway, on a separate thread or not.

Comment: @Danilo7 Can you show that C# code? That would make things more clear. If you already have a working wrapper with DllImport, things will be quite easy and not much is missing.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make a monitor to receive these interrupts continuously? (Infinite loop in DLL)?

Infinite loop *on a separate thread* in your DLL, yes. Either that, or some kind of non-blocking polling (`WaitForSingleObject` with a 0 timeout) that you call periodically from your code.

> an efficient method to trigger an event in C# from this DLL

I wouldn't use events, I'd use an `async` call that waits for the next trigger and returns, like this:

```
async Task WaitForDriverTrigger()
{
    await Task.Run(() => WaitForSingleObject(@event, -1));
}

// called like:
await WaitForDriverTrigger();
```

Keep in mind that we're crossing thread boundaries here, and the async machinery can take care of it for you (like in the above example, the resulting continuation is back on your main thread).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion
The events are in the C++ DLL I can't think of a different way to get notified by the PCIe board. I am using events because that's used in the test app of the device

Comment: You’re conflating kernel synchronisation events with C# events and it’s making it difficult to understand what your objection is. Could you clarify which of the two you have a problem with?